# how to reduce apk size without splitting when linked with opencv native libs?

Tags: android, opencv, size, apk

I have developed an android app that uses opencv library to process images. Currently my APK size is 80Mb. To reduce its size I used splitting apk, and its size became about 10 to 30Mb depending on cpu architecture. I'm going to release my app on a local android market not on google play store. But then I realized that the android store which I want to release my application on it, is not supporting apk splitting, Now I have to reduce the apk size without splitting. What are other ways to do this? I'm just using the Core, Imgproc and Imgcodecs modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is nothing bad in splitting apk in multiple cpu architecture.
- You can not make `opencv` `.so` files smaller which is already packaged.

**If one user is downloading apk, you should ensure that all data is useful for user who is spending his time and data on our apk.**

**Solution :** I am happy that Google mind this and have [Multiple APK support](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks). As title you can upload multiple apk targeting multiple cpu's.

So just don't worry about size and go ahead with Multiple APK support.

**Update :**

You can use only `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a` and `x86` to make apk smaller because other cpu architecture have negligible devices in world.

See [Unity statistics per architecture and CPU features](https://web.archive.org/web/20171113032047/https://hwstats.unity3d.com/mobile/cpu-android.html)

ARMv7: 98.1%

Intel x86: 1.7%

[image]

Comment: I edited my question, see it please. I'm not going to release it on google play.

Comment: You can hire c, c++ developers to compress code of openCV libraries as your per your need. Thing is that libraries have whole code that can be useful for some module. And we have to go along with that. Because we can't go through that libraries again. There can be much code that is not useful for you, but you have to take that with you.

Comment: After searching about different ABIs, I decided to support 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a' and  'arm64-v8a' and removed opencv libs for other architectures, since there isn't any android device with 'x86_64' or 'mips' architecture and 'armeabi' is  deprecated too. My APK size is now 35MB. Its not that small but acceptable and much better than hiring a new c++ developer.

Comment: Cool that's what i do, but i did not tell because some developers need to make compatible app for all devices. I updated answer too, you can consider armeabi-v7a instead arm64-v8a, as this works well in my 2-3 apps.